# PHP Put form data back into form after form validation

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a contact form which it's action is `contact.php`. `Contact.php` has all the form validation. `Index.php` has the form. When I click send on the form and one of the input tags are invalid it sends me back and tells me which input tags were incorrectly filled. The problem is all the other input values that were correct are now empty. Is there a way to save the original values of the input tags with out using `$_GET`? I would use `$_GET`, but I have a message textarea which can go up to 1000 characters. And I don't want 1000 characters in the URL.

Comment: With the going back and forth between 2 files it would need to redirect with a querystring passing those variables back to the form. If you put both the logic and HTML in the same file, then after your validation is done you can simply reuse the $_POST vars further down the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is your validation taking place in a function for a file that does not contain the form? Your validation should take place in `index.php` and then you can use `$_POST`.  If all goes through then redirect the user to the next page.

```
<input type="text" name="my_input" value="<?=isset($_POST['my_input']) ? $_POST['my_input'] : NULL?>
```

The above uses a ternary operator and says that the value of the input is either going to be the `$_POST` value for this input (`$_POST['my_input']`) or it will be `NULL`.  What determines whether it will be one or the other is whether `isset($_POST['my_input']` is true or not.

Comment: Not in the same file... contact.php vrs index.php

Comment: I see what you're saying, but any kind of redirect should be killed if validation fails.  User should stay on the form page and be forced to fix whatever it is they need to fix before being sent to a different page.  So he should move the validation to `index.php`.

Comment: Yeah... or move everything to contact.php, "go to contact to contact, stay on contact until contacted".

Comment: I was trying to make the validation on another page to make it easier to read the file, but this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a session variable, so in `contact.php` you could set for example `$_SESSION['form_data'] = $_POST;`, which you then could access from `index.php`.

Or you could use for example a jQuery validator to validate the text before the form was submitted.

Comment: This most directly answers the question. Although all this passing data around isn't really needed.

Answer (score 0):

single-page.php

```
<?php

if ($_POST['action'] === 'doit') {
    // Validation and other logic
    // Send email using $_POST['email'] etc.
}

?>

<form>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="doit" />
<input type="submit" value="Contact" />
</form>
```